# Psychopy text wrap issue

Tags: python, psychopy

I am trying to replicate a psychology experiment for my graduate thesis. I am pretty new to psychopy and python coding. Through my online search I managed to add input text functionality to my experiment. There is a slight issue though: When participant inputs the answer sometimes the text is not wrapped and goes beyond the screen. I wrapped the text within the components dialog box but it didn't work. The code that makes the input text function possible is as below:

```
 inputText = "" 
 cursorCounter=0
 cursorVariable='|'
 theseKeys=""
 shift_flag = False
 text_3.alignHoriz ='left'`
 if cursorCounter >= 30:
if cursorVariable=='|':
    cursorVariable=' '
else:
    cursorVariable='|'
    cursorCounter=0
    cursorCounter+=1

 n= len(theseKeys)
 i = 0
 while i < n:

if theseKeys[i] == 'return' and len(inputText) > 4:
    # pressing RETURN means time to stop
    continueRoutine = False
    break

elif theseKeys[i] == 'backspace':
    inputText = inputText[:-1]  # lose the final character
    i = i + 1

elif theseKeys[i] == 'space':
    inputText += ' '
    i = i + 1

elif theseKeys[i] in ['lshift', 'rshift']:
    shift_flag = True
    i = i + 1

elif theseKeys[i] == 'period':
    inputText = inputText + "."
    i = i + 1

elif theseKeys[i] == 'comma':
    inputText = inputText + ","
    i = i + 1

else:
    if len(theseKeys[i]) == 1:
        # we only have 1 char so should be a normal key, 
        # otherwise it might be 'ctrl' or similar so ignore it
        if shift_flag:
            inputText += chr( ord(theseKeys[i]) - ord(' '))
            shift_flag = False
        else:
            inputText += theseKeys[i]

    i = i + 1
    inputText = inputText.capitalize()
    # let's store the final text string into the results finle...
    thisExp.addData('inputText', inputText)
    inputText=""
```

There is also one little problem that when inputted text is too large it also moves upwards and overlap with other texts above the question. I believe these are simple issues but unfortunately I lack the knowledge to fix them. I would be really glad if you can help me out!

Comment: You need to describe exactly what you mean by " I wrapped the text within the components dialog box but it didn't work."

Comment: one of the text component calls the input text as a variable. I opened up that text component's dialog box and set the text wrap to 1.5. nevertheless the text input is not being wrapped.